# What type of transformer is this and what should I be looking for?

Tags: transformer, identification, buying

[image: 4 output transformer]

I'm aware it's a step down transformer but you know how some transformers are 9-0-9 v transformers, yeah, what's this?

By what should I be looking for, i mean what should I type if I'm googling it for example?

Comment: What does the label say?  The output specs appear to be there, but I can't quite read them in the photo.  Can you get a close-up, in-focus picture of the label?

Comment: The label on top tells you.

Answer (score 3):

> *you know how some transformers are 9-0-9 v transformers, yeah, what's
> this?*

[image]

It's got a primary winding (red wires) rated at 220 volts and 50 Hz

It's got two secondary windings (isolated from each other) of: -

- 8.2 volts at a full load current of 3 amps (Black wires)
- 9.2 volts at a full load current of 1.5 amps (Blue wires)